# QLineEdit cursor moves to end after textChanged() or commitData()

Tags: qt, qtableview, qlineedit, qtextcursor

I have a `QTableView` with one column that uses a `QLineEdit` as its editor delegate, and other columns that need to update dynamically as the user types into the `QLineEdit` (e.g. one of the columns contains the length of the text typed in the `QLineEdit` and it should update as the user types, not waiting for them to hit Enter to commit).

I used this code: [Qt: Signal while a QTableView item data is being edited instead of after edit is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081033/qt-signal-while-a-qtableview-item-data-is-being-edited-instead-of-after-edit-is) which mostly works.  It connects the `QLineEdit textChanged()` signal to the editor's `commitData()` signal.

The problem with this code is that as the user types, the `QLineEdit`'s insertion cursor always jumps to the end.  If you are appending text to the end of the line that's fine.  But if the user wants to insert or edit text in the middle of the line, every time they type one letter, the text insertion cursor jumps to the end of the `QLineEdit`. After each keystroke they have to reposition the cursor in order to finish the insertion/edit in the middle.

If I disable the mapper then the cursor doesn't jump, so it isn't something inherent to the editor delegate; it only happens when using the code from the question linked above.

I looked at the code for `QLineEdit textChanged()` and `commitData()` but I can't figure out what is causing the cursor to jump to the end of the `QLineEdit`.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Moving the cursor inside of QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11683311/608639).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remember last text cursor position and then set it manually like this:

```
int pos = lineEdit->cursorPosition();
// change text
lineEdit->setCursorPosition(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, [much better answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/150854/preventing-cursor-moving-after-text-property-is-set/2?_=1697191976808).

If a `QDataWidgetMapper` is involved, the `addMapping` option can not only set the widget, but also which property should be changed. By creating a custom property with a set function with what @Amartel wrote. There is one extra trick: by setting the custom property for example "text2" as `user property`, no additions to `addMapping` are required at all, since it will send the change to the `user property` by default, which stores the cursor, sets the text, and restores the cursor position.